# AsyncTaskLoader endless onCanceled call

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, asynctaskloader

I am creating an AsyncTaskLoader based on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html. When I run my app, according to my logging, the app endlessly oscillates between `loadInBackground` and `onCanceled`. Does anyone know why this error might happen? My BroadcastReceiver is based on [Proper notification of AsyncTaskLoader about data changes from background thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18985067/proper-notification-of-asynctaskloader-about-data-changes-from-background-thread).

Here is my loadInBackground method:

```
 @Override     
 public List<MyItem> loadInBackground() {     

    List<MyItem> items = createDummyData();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).sendBroadcast(new Intent(RECEIVER_FILTER_STRING));     

     Log.d(TAG,”custom loader send broadcast from background and send items: "+items.size());     

     return items;      
}
```

Here is my `onStartLoading`

```
@Override
  protected void onStartLoading() {
    Log.d(TAG, "items loader onStartLoading");
    if (null != mData) {
      Log.d(TAG, "items loader onStartLoading mData not null");
      //someone is calling to start the loader, so if we have data, deliver it now
      deliverResult(mData);
    }

    if (null == mReceiver) {
      Log.d(TAG, "items loader onStartLoading register receiver");
      mReceiver = new LoaderBroadcastReceiver(this);
      LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).
          registerReceiver(mReceiver, new IntentFilter(RECEIVER_FILTER_STRING));
    }

    if (takeContentChanged() || null == mData) {
      //if data has changed since the last time it was loaded or is not available, then:
      Log.d(TAG, "items loader onStartLoading onChange forceLoad");
      forceLoad();
    }
  }
```

Here is my Receiver

```
class LoaderBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private Loader loader;

    public LoaderBroadcastReceiver(Loader loader) {
      this.loader = loader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Log.d(TAG, "loader receiver informing of oonContentChagned");
      loader.onContentChanged();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When it loads in background, it sends the Broadcast, and the Broadcast called `onContentChanged()` that's why the current Loader is cancelled and rerun again.

You should simply remove the BroadcastReceiver, or the BroadcastReceiver should not call onContentChanged().

From the link you quoted, the BroadcastReceiver is used for something like this, e.g. you loader load the file list in a folder, and for some reason you know that new files is added, so you send the Broadcast (**not from your loader**) and force the loader to rerun and get new content.

> public void onContentChanged () Added in API level 11
>
> Called when Loader.ForceLoadContentObserver detects a change. The
>   default implementation checks to see if the loader is currently
>   started; if so, it simply calls forceLoad();